# Get percentage of overlap between two multipolygons in R

Tags: r, geometry, gis, raster, r-sf

I have two MULTYPOLYGONS, one where a row is a election district*year pair, and the other is a collection of flood events.

```
 district.df
      year ward_ons     cycle                       geometry
    1 2007       E1   NA-2007 POLYGON ((527370.8 183470.7...
    2 2008       E1 2007-2008 POLYGON ((528891.1 182192.6...
    3 2009       E2   NA-2009 POLYGON ((370294.2 414678.7...
    4 2010       E3   NA-2010 POLYGON ((375025.4 414992.1...
    5 2011       E3 2010-2011 POLYGON ((375150.8 410809.8...
    6 2018       E3 2011-2018 POLYGON ((373286.3 414364.5...
    7 2007       E4   NA-2007 POLYGON ((373168.6 411597.8...
    8 2010       E4 2007-2010 POLYGON ((374783.2 406209.4...
```

Flood data:

```
    flood.df
    Simple feature collection with 8 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 317656.2 ymin: 90783.2 xmax: 546460.6 ymax: 631125.7
projected CRS:  OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
  year            name                       geometry
1 2007      River 2007 POLYGON ((359637.7 268239.7...
2 2007       Tank 2007 POLYGON ((325444.1 92717.57...
3 2008  Yorkshire 2008 POLYGON ((318550.7 103058.8...
4 2009 Flood East 2009 POLYGON ((541472.6 112593, ...
5 2010  Occurence 2010 MULTIPOLYGON (((545863.4 11...
6 2012      Storm 2012 POLYGON ((473637.4 103927, ...
7 2011      Flood 2011 MULTIPOLYGON (((524617.6 42...
8 2017      River 2017 POLYGON ((393387.6 631125.7...
```

What I am trying to do is to get a column in the election district multypolygon which is the share of its area that overlaps with *any* of the polygons in the flood multipolygon with the same value for `year`.

This is what I tried (influenced by https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140504/extracting-intersection-areas-in-r)

```
# Create function
overlap.fraction <- function(election, flood, yeari){
  flood.year <- flood[flood$year == yeari,]
  election.year <- election[election$year == yeari, ]
for (i in 1:nrow(election.year)){
  int.i <- as_tibble(st_intersection(i, flood.year))
  int.i$affected <- st_area(int.i$geoms)
  affected.by.county(paste0(yeari)) <- int.i%>%
  dplyr::group_by(code) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(affected.area = sum(affected))
}
}
```

And then tried it

```
i.1990 <- overlap.fraction(district.df, flood.df, yeari = 1990)
```

But keep getting:

```
Error in UseMethod("st_intersection") : no applicable method for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

I tried different alterations to the function and the loop inside it. Ideally, I would even get a function or loop that would do it at once instead of having to do it for every year, as is the case for what I am trying here. I am doing it this way because I am getting closer to getting it done this way, but I understand this is not the most effective way.

Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's create a function to do it *by year*.

```
library(sf)

## storing years in a variable
years <- unique(district.df$year)

## creating an "auxiliary" geometry
flood.df$geom_2 <- st_geometry(flood.df)

## function to calculate this "proportion of intersection"
## inputs: y = year; dt1 = dataset1 (district); dt2 = dataset2(flood)
prop_intersect <- function(y, dt1, dt2) {
  ## filtering year
  out1 <- dt1[dt1$year == y,]
  out2 <- dt2[dt2$year == y,]

  ## calculating the areas for the first dataset
  out1 <- transform(out1, dist_area = as.numeric(st_area(geometry)))

  ## joining the datasets (polygons that intersect will be joined).
  ## It would be nice to have id variables for both datasets
  output <- st_join(
    x    = out1,
    y    = out2,
    join = st_intersects
  )

  ## calculating area of intersection
  output <- transform(output, 
                      inter_area = mapply(function(x, y) {
                                      as.numeric(sf::st_area(
                                           sf::st_intersection(x, y)
                                       ))}, x = geometry, y = geom_2))

  ## calculating proportion of intersected area
  output <- transform(output, prop_inter = inter_area/dist_area)

  return(output)
}
```

So, now we have a function to do what you request. It is very likely that there exists a better (more efficient and "clean") way to do it. However, this is what I could come up with. Also, since this is not a `reprex`, it is hard for me to know whether this code works or not.

That being said, now we can iterate on "year" as follows

```
final_df <- lapply(years, prop_intersect, dt1 = district.df, dt2 = flood.df)

final_df <- do.call("rbind", final_df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much and don't worry about it not being the most efficient and clean. As long as it does the trick, I'm happy!
When running the function on my data I keep getting the following though: Error in year == y : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: Also, apologies on it not being a reprex. I'm quite new to shapefiles and sf so I find it hard to replicate geometries here, any tip is much welcome

Comment: No worries about not being a `reprex`, sometimes it happens. Hm, that's weird. I'm not sure what's going on. By any chance do you have any subset of the data that you can share?  Maybe there is another variable named `year` in your global environment.

Comment: @AntVal what does `unique(district.df$year)` return?

Comment: So I changed   out1 <- dt1[year == y,]
  out2 <- dt2[year == y,] for   out1 <- dt1[dt1$year == y,]
  out2 <- dt2[dt2$year == y,], and the code now runs. Issue is that the output has far more observations than the original election_df does.

Comment: unique(district.df$year) returns: [1] 1996 2008 2006 1990 2004 1991 1995 2000 1994 2003 1999 2002 1993 1998 2007 1992 2005 2001 1997 2009 2012 2014 2011
[24] 2013 2015 2016 2017 2018

Comment: What would be the best way to share the data/part of it?

Comment: oh, you fixed it! This is the expected result. It has more observations because every polygon in the first data set has one line for each polygon of the second line that intersects with it.

Comment: Yes, ofc! So with final_df%>%group_by(district, year)%>%summarise(prop_inter = sum(prop_inter)) I get the share of each district that is overlapping with a flood object of that same year, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right! By the way, this looks like a cool application. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you! And thanks so much for all the help. Life saving! All the best

Comment: btw @lcgodoy if you have the time/patience/interest I have a similar query for these project here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098097/test-intersection-of-multipolygons-based-on-year-intervals-in-r Thanks!